# I want to know if my laptop hardware supports ubuntu 20.04

Tags: compatibility

My laptop is an Acer Aspire 3 A315-55G.
it has:

- (CPU)Intel i5-8265 processor
- (GPU)Nvidia mx230 2gb
- (RAM)8GB

Is it advisable to move to Linux with a graphic card like that? Does the drivers give problems?

Comment: You could just [try Ubuntu before installing it](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started). Same with almost any other distro.

Comment: After you install Ubuntu, you will need to run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install the proprietary Nvidia drivers. Since Acer doesn't sell laptops with Ubuntu preinstalled, you will just have to try it out and see if it works. Before you begin, make sure to create a rescue media for Windows in case something goes wrong, you can reinstall Windows. Also, back up your data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple answer to this. Try it out! Simply download the desktop image of the Ubuntu version you want to run, burn it to a USB memory stick and then boot from the stick. Boot in to "Try Ubuntu" and, if its boots successfully, you can install Ubuntu on to your disk.

Two points:

1. Don't do this with a server image! That does not have a live version.
2. Make sure you click on the Try Ubuntu and not Install Ubuntu.